# RxJS Observable reset timeout

Tags: timeout, rxjs, observable

Is it possible to reset/increase the timeout of an Observable after another timeout has already been set? In the following example the timeout of 5 should be overriden with a timeout of 9999, but this does not work:

```
var source = Rx.Observable
.return(42)
.delay(1000)
.timeout(5)
.timeout(9999); // this statement should override the previous set timeout of 5 MS, but actually it does not

var subscription = source.subscribe(
function (x) {
    console.log('Next: ' + x);
},
function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);   
},
function () {
    console.log('Completed');   
});
```

Are there any possibilities to override the already set timeout?

Comment: Can you resubscribe when you want to change the timeout? Then you could do it on subscribe time, like source.timeout(timeoutVariable).subscribe(....), and desubscribing - resubscribing when timeoutVariable changes.... Actually, is there any way to put this change event into a stream? Edit - yup, submitting posible answer

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** As far as I know, there is no *"legit"* solution to this.

---

**Hacky answer:**  You could connect to the `source` of the `timeout`-ed stream and set your own timeout, see the example below how this could be done.
However, I would **not** advise you to do that in any seriouse project - I'm sure there should be another solution to your problem.

```js
var base = Rx.Observable
.return(42)
.delay(1000)
.timeout(1);

var patched = base.source.timeout(2000);

var subscription = patched.subscribe(
function (x) {
    console.log('Patched Next: ' + x);
},
function (err) {
    console.log('Patched Error: ' + err);   
},
function () {
    console.log('Patched Completed');   
});

var subscription = base.subscribe(
function (x) {
    console.log('Base Next: ' + x);
},
function (err) {
    console.log('Base Error: ' + err);   
},
function () {
    console.log('Base Completed');   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if you use a subject to represent your timeout value?

```
timeoutSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
timeoutSubject
    .asObservable()
    .switchMap((v) => source.timeout(v))
    .subscribe((r) => console.log(r));

timeoutSubject.next(5);
timeoutSubject.next(9999);
```

switchMap should take handle of the unsubscribing/resubscribing for each one of the timeout values.